# Timestamp convert into shortcode with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using this code to detect timestamp from content.

```
$pattern = '/(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])/';
$replacement = '[spp-timestamp time="$0"]';
$foundTimestamp = preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement, $content);
```

To detect timestamp to shortcode [spp-timestamp time="00:00"]

Just want to add more logic into this to not select timestamp from selected div for example

```
<div class="sm2-inline-duration timestamp">0:00</div> and 
<div class="sm2-inline-time timestamp">0:00</div>
```

for example if i put class "timestamp" in any div it should not selected with regex.

Is it possible ?

Right now its is detecting stamps

00:00, 00:00:00, 0:00, 0:00:00, and not selecting with Am or PM

Comment: Use DOM parsing and `//div[not(contains(@class, "timestamp"))]` xpath to exclude modifying the contents of the `div` elements that contain `timestamp` in their `class` attributes. The regex will become much easier then.

Comment: Can you show me how with the above regex included. Because in php i can preg_replace the stamps into shortcode ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the HTML with `DOMDocument` with `XPath` that will allow you to use a simpler regex for your replacement. `//div[not(contains(@class, "timestamp"))]` xpath expression will prevent modifying the contents of the `div` elements that contain `timestamp` substring in their `class` attributes.

```
$html = <<<DATA
<body>
<div class="sm2-inline-duration timestamp">0:00</div>
<div class="sm2-inline-time timestamp">0:00</div>
<div class="sm2-inline-duration">0:00</div>
<div class="sm2-inline-duration">Do not touch this</div>
</body>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$pattern = '/(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)/i';
$replacement = '[spp-timestamp time="$0"]';

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[not(contains(@class, "timestamp"))]');

foreach($divs as $div) { 
   $div->nodeValue = preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement, $div->nodeValue);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OWt5ky)

*For educational purposes*, here is a regex-based approach as *this will not work in production safely with arbitrary HTML*.

The idea is to replace the unsupported negative lookbehind of inifinite width with an optional capturing group, and check inside `preg_replace_callback` if  the group matched, and use the appropriate replacement (if matched, we need to keep the original match text, else, replace with our custom replacement).

```
$pattern = '/(<div\s+[^<]*?\bclass="[^<"]*\btimestamp\b[^<]*?>[^<]*)?(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])/';
$replacement = '[spp-timestamp time="$0"]';
$foundTimestamp = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($m) {
    return empty($m[1]) ? '[spp-timestamp time="'. $m[0] . '"]' : $m[0];
}, $content);
echo $foundTimestamp;
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/tDUO36)

Comment: Thank you so much for this... :)